# Is IE-11 still supported Lightning Experience?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, browser, ie-11

According to Salesforce Document about supported Browser, Salesforce will end IE-11 Lightning Experience at 2020/12/31. But today, when I login my Org with IE-11, I still can change to Lightning Experience.

So I want to asked is IE-11 Lightning Experience support extended again? Or do I misunderstand this document?

Document Link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_browsers_sfx.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enabled [Extended IE 11 Support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000333934&type=1&mode=1), you had until December 31st, 2020 to move on to another browser. At this point, IE 11 support has been completely discontinued. Even if, for some reason, you can use IE 11 with Lightning today, any bugs you encounter will not be supported by Technical Support.

Comment: Thanks for you share the information, it's clear now.

Answer (score 0):

In the help doc, it is mentioned " Spport for Internet Explorer 11 to access Lightning Experience is retiring beginning in Summer ’16."  Which indicates the Support will be discontinued.

Even if you can open LEX in IE but it will have serious performance issues + alot of standards after ES5 are not implemented in IE, considering LWC architecture which is built upon ES7 stack, it would not completely support for IE either.

I would recommend using a Modern Web Browser for LEX.

Answer (score 0):

In short, **NO support for lightning in IE11 anymore**.

If you open salesforce in IE now, it does not give an option to switch to lightning anymore. Maybe they are applying this update in a phase by phase manner, but in few days you wont be able to see that switch button anymore.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explain, I will check this again after few days.